# Distribution of the difference of two uniformly distributed variables subject to a condition!

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be three independent uniformly distributed random variables on $(0,1)$. The variables are admissible if and only if $a<b<c$.

I want to find the distribution of $B-C$ given that the triple is admissible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My answer does not give you that distribution but reaches you the possibility to find it yourself. I presume that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are independent. This should be mentioned in your question. Note that $P\left[A<B<C\right]=\frac{1}{6}$. If I understand you correctly then you are searching for:$$P\left[B-C\leq x\mid A<B<C\right]=6P\left[B-C\leq x\wedge A<B<C\right]=$$

$$6\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\left[b-c\leq x\wedge a<b<c\right]dadbdc$$

where $x$ is fixed and $\left[b-c\leq x\wedge a<b<c\right]$ denotes
the characteristic function on $\left(0,1\right)^{3}$ of set $\left\{ \left(a,b,c\right)\in\left(0,1\right)^{3}\mid b-c\leq x\wedge a<b<c\right\} $.

Comment: @Stefanos Yes, off course. Thank you.

Comment: @drhab, Thanks, I think I nailed it. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Given: random variables $A$, $B$ and $C$ have joint pdf $f(a,b,c)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/pdfXYZ.png))</sub>

Let $Z = B-C$. Then, the cdf of $Z$ is $P(Z<z) = P(B-C<z)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/cdfofdiff.png))</sub>

Take the derivative of the cdf wrt $z$ to yield the desired pdf, say $g(z)$:

$$g(z) = 3(1+z)^2   \qquad \text{ for } -1<z<0$$

All done.

**Notes**

1. The `Prob` function used above is from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*. As disclosure, I should add that I am one of the authors.

Answer (score 0):

$A,B$ and $C$ are independent uniformly distributed variables. We want to find the distribution of $B-C$ given that $A<B<C$. Note that $P[A<B<C]=\frac{1}{6}$. Call $F_{B-C}$ the distribution function of $B-C$.
$F_{B-C}(z)=P[B-C<=z|A<B<C]=\frac{P[B-C\leq z \wedge A<B<C]}{Prob[A<B<C]}=6P[B-C\leq z \wedge A<B<C]$.

Now we look closer at the condition $B-C<=z \wedge A<B<C$. For a given triple $(a,b,c)$, these three conditions must be satisfied (1) $0<a<1+z$ (2) $a<b<1+z$ (3) $b-z<c<1$.

If follows $F_{B-C}(z)=6 \int_{0}^{1+z} \int_{a}^{1+z} \int_{b-z}^{1} dc db da =(1+z)^3$. This is only valid if $-1<z<0$.

The density function is therefore $\partial F_{B-C}(z)/\partial z= 3(1+z)^2$ for $-1<z<0$ and zero otherwise.